# How does "%tB" formatter work?

Tags: java, exception, format

```
System.out.format("%tB",12);
```

I should get a "December" out of it, however i get a nice exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: b != java.lang.Integer
```

It means the syntax I used is wrong.
I cannot find any reference on line explaining the `%tB` formatting command.
Is anybody help to clarify the matter?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your way of questioning is cool ! +1 for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`Formatter` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html):

> Date/Time - may be applied to Java types which are capable of encoding
>   a date or time: `long`, `Long`, `Calendar`, and `Date`.

You can get rid of the exception by using a long integer such as `12L`. But note that **the formatter is expecting an integer representation of a date** (i.e. a Unix timestamp with millisecond precision).

In order to get what you want, you can try to manually build an approximate timestamp in a middle of a month in 1970 :

```
int month = 12;
int millisecondsInDay = 24*60*60*1000;
long date = ((month - 1L)*30 + 15)*millisecondsInDay;
System.out.format("%tB", date);
```

Or simply use a `Date` object :

```
System.out.format("%tB", new Date(0, 12, 0));
```

Also note that **you can do the same thing without `Formatter`** :

```
java.text.DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getMonths()[12-1];
```

See [`DateFormatSymbols`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html#getMonths%28%29) for more information.

Comment: oh that's funny. Directly from an oracle tutorial "tB formats an integer as a locale-specific month name." reference http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html

Comment: Hi zakinster, do you know any reference for better understanding the java formatters? I have not been able to find anything detailed in the javadoc or any oracle tutorial about it.

Comment: @Rollerball looks like a pretty wrong or at least misleading sentance.

Comment: On the same site, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html is quite extensive and not misleading.

Comment: @Rollerball The oracle tutorial is actually correct, the formatter can handle an integer, but only a `long` one and it must represent a  unix timestamp with millisecond precision.

Answer (score 2):

A sample prog

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Formatter;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Formatter fmt = new Formatter();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    fmt.format("Today is day %te of %<tB, %<tY", cal);
    System.out.println(fmt);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Satya, do you know any reference for better understanding the java formatters? I have not been able to find anything detailed in the javadoc or any oracle tutorial about it.

Comment: @Rollerball well, this javadoc pretty much covers it all: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html