# java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: A != java.lang.String Why can i print the date

Tags: java, calendar

I'm trying to print the date out but it's not working in the format that i need it to be

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Calendar;

    public class MartinezC001PA2
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);//for user input
        Calendar dateTime = Calendar.getInstance();//to get date and time

        String userName = "";
        String stockStatus = String.format("\n\nSTOCK PURCHASES FOR %S \nAS OF %1$TA, %1$TB %1$Td, %1$TY", userName, dateTime);

        System.out.print(stockStatus);
      }//END MAIN

    }
```

Comment: What do you expect it to look like? What does it look like currently?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask. I suggest searching StackOverflow for "java date format" for many examples. Even wiser would be a search for "joda format".

Answer (score -1):

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

Comment: you can refer this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232447/how-does-tb-formatter-work